# how to create Date from data string in typescript (react) where string should be treated as GMT? (code attached)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date-fns

In React/Typescript how can I create a Date from a datetime string (received from a REST API), where the assumption is that it is UTC time.

String in question is: "2022-01-31T14:00:00".   So it doesn't have the "Z" at the end which seems to be created when I try creating it manually.  It's a datetime string I am receiving from a REST API so I'm a bit stuck with this.

So in the console out you see I am getting:

> 2022-01-31T14:00:00  =>  Monday, January 31st, 2022 at 2:00:00 PM
> GMT+10:00

But I really what to get the following (assuming I'm running this in the +10H timezone):

> 2022-01-31T14:00:00  =>  Tuesday, March 1st, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM
> GMT+10:00

Code

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

const tsCreatedDate = new Date(2022, 2, 1)
console.log("Starting Date: ", format(tsCreatedDate, 'PPPPpppp'))

const tsCreatedDateStr = tsCreatedDate.toISOString()
const dateStrFromApi: string = "2022-01-31T14:00:00"

const parsedApiDate = new Date(dateStrFromApi)
const parsedTsDate = new Date(tsCreatedDateStr)

console.log("Typescript Direct: ", tsCreatedDateStr, " => ", format(parsedTsDate , 'PPPPpppp'))
console.log("WEB API Date Str : ", dateStrFromApi  , " => ", format(parsedApiDate, 'PPPPpppp'))
```

Console:

```
Starting Date:  Tuesday, March 1st, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+10:00
src/App.tsx:12
Typescript Direct:  2022-02-28T14:00:00.000Z  =>  Tuesday, March 1st, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+10:00
src/App.tsx:20
WEB API Date Str :  2022-01-31T14:00:00  =>  Monday, January 31st, 2022 at 2:00:00 PM GMT+10:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you want is: new `Date(parsedApiDate.setHours(parsedApiDate.getHours() + 10))`
Where 10 is options. 10 here is your timezone.

Comment: the issue is the date string I have is a local timezone - so I want to parse the string as the local timezone not as UTC

Comment: Would you want is: `new Date(parsedApiDate.setHours(parsedApiDate.getHours() + 10))`
Where 10 is options. 10 here is your timezone.

Comment: yep this worked thanks (proabably should look to access the "10" programmtically) - did you want to update the answer so I can select it

Comment: I just update my answer. Nice to help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using moment js.

```
moment(new Date(dateStrFromApi).getTime()).utc().format()
```

Albert

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work